# Dropdown menu using child structure pages

Tags: ee2, structure, children

I have the following code and I'm trying to make it so that the children page titles populate in the dropdown listing and then link to that page. Any

```
                                        {exp:structure:entries dynamic="off"}
                                        {machine_support_category}
                                        <div style="padding: 0 20px 32px;text-align: center;width: 263px; float:left;">

                                            <div class="product-img-box">
                                                <a class="product-image" href="#"><img width="173" height="117" alt="Image description" src="{image}"></a>
                                            </div>
                                            <h3 class="product-name"><a href="#">{title}</a></h3>
                                            <select>
                                                {structure:child_listing:channel_id}
                                                <option>{title}</option>
                                                {structure:child_listing:channel_id}
                                            </select>

                                        </div>
                                        {/machine_support_category}
                                        {/exp:structure:entries}
```

Backend Pages Structure:

[image]

Frontend:

[image]

Comment: What is jour question?

Comment: "I'm trying to make it so that the children page titles populate in the dropdown" How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

looks like you are mixing up a few things - Structure can render your menu with a variety of tags, as listed on their [documentation page](http://buildwithstructure.com/documentation/navigation_examples). You will find that there are limited options for a dropdown menu, but with some css tinkering you will be able to build a basic version.

If this doesn't meet your requirements you might need to resort to Peter Lewis's [Structure Entries](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/structure-entries) Addon.

If all if this is something you have already tried then I would suggest you ask for Structure's [support](http://structure.tenderapp.com) - they are good and very matter of fact.